# How Do We Nagios On AWS Autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios

Previously, setting up Nagios server to do monitoring is easy since every agent servers are static. But now, here comes AWS. How do we design/configure such that a Nagios server can automatically push correct check configurations to each of the servers scaled up/down and how do we know what when a server is scaled down or up, Nagios will not say that it was an alert or a problem and instead it will tell that "it's your server being scaled down".

IP addresses in AWS is not static after the ASG scaled up/down servers. How do we pull that information, too? And tell to Nagios to be aware of new settings that the servers have. Might be that when servers get scaled down, delete config from Nagios, and when servers get scaled up, push config to Nagios. And immediately do active checks to the hosts and services.

Comment: nagios is a mess in the modern cloud world with systems coming up and down rapidly. I'd highly recommend you look at replacing nagios with sensu https://sensuapp.org/ It can use all the same nagios checks but is designed for the modern cloud world. If you have to use nagios then you need to need a way to automate the host management like this https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Automated_Host_Management.pdf

Comment: I argued several months ago that we should monitor services at the aggregate, not the individual service points or servers. If that doesn't work for you,  you could use a startup script on the new servers to sftp a config file to the Nagios server, have a script validate the config and move it into the config directory then reload Nagios on a regular basis.  
Also when detecting a server down, have the down script ensure the server should still be active and if not, remove it from the config directory Non-trivial, but doable.

Comment: Hi. Can you please share approach to benefit others if you have implemented it?

Answer (score 1):

The client side isn't really any different in AWS -- your AMI or configuration management system sets up NRPE, installs plugins, etc, as required for your environment.

The server side is where everything goes wild.  As you note, AWS ASGs are dynamic, so your Nagios configuration needs to be dynamic, too.  Practically, that means that the "source of truth" for your configuration needs to live somewhere outside of Nagios, and you have something that queries that data store and writes the configuration files (and reloads Nagion) when anything changes.  Your scripting language of choice will come in handy here.  For the "source of truth", there's any number of service registration and discovery systems that'll do the trick, but for simple use cases querying the EC2 API to get a list of instances works quite well.

You then need to teach your EC2 instances to register themselves with your chosen service discovery system on startup, and deregister themselves when they terminate cleanly.  There's a strong argument to be made that you shouldn't ever care when a single machine dies, and I agree with it, but if you're using Nagios, your organisation's mindset is probably very set on "machines are important!", and trying to change that overnight is going to be a struggle, so you might have to learn over time that you're in the cattle-herding business now, not running a pet store.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @womble, Your nagios solution should be dynamic. [Check this blog](https://web-need.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-use-nagios-to-monitor-services.html) which explains entire solution with scripts and it is working perfectly fine for me.